# Is possible to trade game items or gold outside of WOW on third party websites?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As a non-WOW player I have wondered: is possible to trade game items or gold outside of the game on third party websites? Does Blizzard have an API or something, or is this kind of activity completely non-sanctioned and takes place in a grey market?

I ask because a friend had thrown out an idea of making an exchange where I could trade World of Warcraft gold for say Second Life currency or Facebook credits, etc. I was wondering if a thing like that was even possible. Sounds like the answer is no.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

It's completely non-sanctioned. [Blizzard's Terms of Use](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/wow_tou.html) have the following section:

> ### Ownership/Selling of the Account or Virtual Items.
>
> Blizzard does not recognize the
> transfer of World of Warcraft Accounts
> or BNET Accounts (each an “Account”).
> You may not purchase, sell, gift or
> trade any Account, or offer to
> purchase, sell, gift or trade any
> Account, and any such attempt shall be
> null and void. Blizzard owns, has
> licensed, or otherwise has rights to
> all of the content that appears in the
> Game. You agree that you have no right
> or title in or to any such content,
> including without limitation the
> virtual goods or currency appearing or
> originating in the Game, or any other
> attributes associated with any
> Account. Blizzard does not recognize
> any purported transfers of virtual
> property executed outside of the Game,
> or the purported sale, gift or trade
> in the “real world” of anything that
> appears or originates in the Game.
> Accordingly, you may not sell in-game
> items or currency for “real” money, or
> exchange those items or currency for
> value outside of the Game.

In other words, trading in-game items for any sort of external reward (be it real money, Second Life money, Facebook credits, or anything else) is prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

**COMPLETE EDIT:**

Yes.  There are two places where you can partake in the auction house out of game:

1.) Blizzard has it's own account addon (~$2/month extra) where you can buy/sell on the auction house out of game.

2.) 3rd party wise, another option (purely observatory) is http://www.wowecon.com/ where you can see the prices of things on the auction house and also view what things have been going for - kinda neat to track patterns of pricing (for instance the weekend inflation that typically happens).

Hope that helps!

Comment: The question said nothing about money, just trading/purchasing items using gold, the in-game currency.

Comment: I guess the phrase "on third party websites" is what primed me to think of the gold/item/toon trade...

Comment: +1 The only way to actually use in-game gold to buy in-game things from outside the game is through Blizzards auction house, which is also available on iPhone through the Armoury app. I have never seen another site or app that allows these transactions, as they are closely guarded by Blizzard so they can charge for the privilege!

Comment: Can you expand on your first point? How does this work? I have never heard of that addon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about trading in-game items for real-world money, then the answer is that it is completely against Blizzard policy.

Comment: The question said nothing about money

Comment: @Nick Did you miss the "if"?